# Pandas .mean() for a column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to find the average for all the values in one of the columns in my dataset. I did df["column"].mean() but It's giving me a ridiculously big number that does not make sense considering how small my values are. The min() and max() function works fine, however.

[Here is what I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoAy0.png)

To clarify, left side of the output in the first cell are the indexes, and right side are the values.

```
delay["If Delayed, for how long?"].astype(int)

print(delay["If Delayed, for how long?"].min())
print(delay["If Delayed, for how long?"].max())
print(delay["If Delayed, for how long?"].mean()
```

Comment: Please include self contained code that enables us to duplicate the issue. Pictures of parts of your code are useless for reproducing your problem.

Comment: This seems like a bug. I am reopening. Can you post the code instead of a picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably pandas should refuse to take the mean of a string column.  But it doesn't, so what you get is:

```
In [154]: s = pd.Series([15,18,16,14,20,16,15]).astype(str)

In [155]: s.sum()
Out[155]: '15181614201615'

In [156]: float(s.sum()) / len(s)
Out[156]: 2168802028802.1428

In [157]: s.mean()
Out[157]: 2168802028802.1428
```

`s.min()` and `s.max()` will "work", but it's the lexicographic minimum and maximum, not the numerical, so '111' < '20'.

Make your column numerical, whether int or float, whichever you prefer, and remember that `.astype` doesn't work in-place, so you'll need

```
delay["If Delayed, for how long?"] = delay["If Delayed, for how long?"].astype(int)
```

if you want the column to actually change.